# Irreducible factors of $x^8 - x$ in $Z/2Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I must find the irreducible factors of $f(x) = x^8 - x$ in $Z/2Z[x]$ and that's what I did:

$f(x) = x(x-1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$

but of course the correct solution is:

$f(x) = x(x-1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)$

I do not understand how I can reach the correct solution by logical reasoning (without going on attempts). The solution of the exercise says:

1) "The irreducible factors are all the irreducible polynomials of degree 1 and 3 alone" Why?

2) "You find exactly $6/3 = 2$ irreducible polynomials of degree 3". Does this happens because the 6th degree polynomial I found is not reducible (since the only ones have degree 1 or 3) and it has no zeros?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you call the *grade* of a polynomial?

Comment: I meant the degree. In my native language you say a word that's very similar to "grade" so I got confused. I rectified the text. Thank you for welcoming :)

Comment: Very close to being a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1136509/11619). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1165610/11619). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1722699/11619).

Comment: I tryed searching if someone else did the same question, but I did not find those links. This is my first day on this website and I still have to get the hang of it. I'm sorry.

Comment: We understand, Matt! Searching here is sometimes difficult because the normal search engines cannot grok LaTeX. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E8-x%24%2C%20%24Z_2%5C%20%24&p=1) is an alternative, but it has other shortcomings. Experience helps. You'll get the hang of it soon enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I note here $GF(p^n)$ the finite field of characteristic $p$ prime having $p^n$ elements.*

The elements of $GF(2^3)$ are the roots of $f$ in a [splitting field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field). Also note that the multiplicative group of $GF(2^3)$ is of order $7$ which is a prime. Hence all elements of the multiplicative group of $GF(2^3)$ except the identity $1$ are of order $7$.

From this it follows that an irreducible factor of $g(x) = x^7-1$ can only be of degree $1$, which is the case for the identity or of degree $3$. If an irreducible polynomial of $g$ would be of degree $2$, $GF(2^3)$ would have a subfield of order $4$ and at least an element of order $3$ which is not the case as we've seen above.

So we're left to find the irreducible polynomials (over $GF(2)$) of degree $3$. This is quite easy. The only polynomials of degree $3$ are:
$$x^3, x^3+1, x^3+x, x^3+x+1, x^3+x^2+1$$

Only the two last ones are irreducible.

We're done.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If it is not a problem, I would like to have some clarification.

I do not understand the following implication:
Let's suppose that $g(x)=x^7−1$ has an irriducible factor of degree $2$ => $GF(2^3)$ would have a subfield of order $4$. 
Maybe you used the following statement:
If $h(x)$ is an irriducibile factor of $g(x)=x^7−1$ of degree m then $(Z/2Z)/(h)≅GL(2^m)$. How can I prove this statement?

Comment: Correcting your isomorphism, it is in fact $GF(2)[x]/(h) \simeq GF(2^m)$. This is a standard result. See for example [Finite field construction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Explicit_construction).